# PostgreSQL how to get closest birthday date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **birthdays** with 2 columns **name** and **date**.
Name is string value, date is date (Looks like this: **1989-07-28 00:00:00**)

How can i get closest birthday, according to day i am checking, for example NOW()

Using PostgreSQL

Comment: I'd suggest, whichever solution you use, to make sure you have test cases around leap years. For example, if someone was born on the 29th of February, and your solution involves creating a Date `2023-02-29` you'd need to be sure PostgreSQL handles this nicely rather than throwing an error.
(and you might want to check if it matters that someone whose birthday is 29th Feb might not be sorted before someone whose birthday is 1 Mar)

Answer (score 0):

The question is determining if the year is this year or next year:

```
select (case when to_char(dob, 'MM-DD') >= to_char(now(), 'MM-DD')
             then to_date(to_char(current_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(dob, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             else to_date(to_char(current_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(dob, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 year'
        end)
from (values ('1989-07-28'::date)) v(dob);
```

Comment: Thanks, i used your advise and it works perfect this way:
```select name, date, (case when to_char(date, 'MM-DD') >= to_char(now(), 'MM-DD') then 
                    to_date(to_char(current_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(date, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') else 
                    to_date(to_char(current_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(date, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval 
                    '1 year' end) from birthdays order by 3```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are searching for forward-looking birthdays, the query below takes the minimum difference in days starting from current date

```
   Select "Date" - Current_Date as diff,
     "Date" as Dob,
      Name
     from birthdays 
    Where  ("Date"- Current_Date) > 0
    Order by 1 asc
    limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off in Postgres if your column is defined as DATE then it does not appear as "1989-07-28 00:00:00". Dates in Postgres do not have time components, so no "00:00:00" (unless you have done something with *datestyle*. But that is actually immaterial here.  
Postgres dates can be directly subtracted to get the days number of between them, with the result either positive or negative depending upon which date occurs first. To
get the "closest" to a specific data just take the absolute value.

```
with birthdays (name, bday) as
   ( values ('George', date '2020-10-18')
          , ('Gloryann', date '2020-11-02')
          , ('Phyllis', date '2020-10-09')
          , ('Sam', date '2020-06-18')
   )
select name, bday birthday 
  from birthdays 
 order by abs(current_date-bday)
 limit 1;
```

***Caution***: Do not use **date** as an object name. Date is both a Postres and SQL standard reserved word. While using it may be permitted currently Postges would be within their right to enforce the predefined meaning at anytime, potentially causing major issues for your app. Play it safe **Do Not** use reserved words as object names.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it works perfect this way:

```
select name, date, (case when to_char(date, 'MM-DD') >= to_char(now(), 'MM-DD') then 
to_date(to_char(current_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(date, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
else to_date(to_char(current_date, 'YYYY') || '-' || to_char(date, 'MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') + interval '1 year' end) 
from birthdays order by 3
```